# OpenSSL Failed for Specific Provider?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, openssl

Our production (Heroku) and development (local) instances have been working when accessing a `https` endpoint. However, within the past 2 days, we started getting the dreaded OpenSSL error:

`OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed`

I've read through a lot of OpenSSL failed posts on StackOverflow and http://railsapps.github.io/openssl-certificate-verify-failed.html.

I have updated to the latest OpenSSL and confirmed it by running the following:

```
ruby -ropenssl -e 'p OpenSSL::OPENSSL_VERSION'
"OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013"
```

However, I'm still getting this error:

`OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed`

when I call `hash = JSON.parse(open(_url).read)` where the `_url` points to a `https` endpoint.

I don't seem to have problems accessing some providers. For example, when I issue: `curl -I https://d2chzxaqi4y7f8.cloudfront.net/gems/rake-0.9.2.2.gem`, it seems to work.

I also tried this in `irb` and it seems to work:

```
require 'open-uri'
open 'https://google.com'
=> #<File:/var/folders/dv/s_2dq32n0ggcn65kn61jtmc80000gn/T/open-uri20130630-887-y2cg2q>
```

Is this something the endpoint provider needs to fix or something with my local and production implementation of OpenSSL?

Answer (score 0):

A certificate verification failure indicates that your Ruby instance was unable to find a way to chain the endpoint's certificate up to a trusted root that it is aware of. This can be a few different things:

- The endpoint may have changed certificate providers and their new source is not in the default trust tore.
- The endpoint may not have the proper intermediates installed.
- The endpoint may have an untrusted certificate on it.

To narrow it down you can try loading the endpoint via a web browser. Do you get an untrusted error then? If so, time to contact your provider. If not, you'll need to look at the certificate and see what root it's using. Then you'll want to add that to the Ruby list of trusted certs (which is sourced differently depending on how you compiled it and on what platform).